# What is the difference between and OB certificate and eIDAS?

Tags: ssl-certificate, open-banking

I'm currently trying to build an OpenBanking application, but I'm having a hard time differentiating between the certificates.
I've generated an OBWAC and OBSEAL certificate, however I can't understand what is the difference between those and a QWAC and QSEAL? Are the latter ones issues by a trusted third-party provider or can I generate them too? Do they have some different fields?

Answer (score 2):

In short, the main difference is that OBWAC and OBSealC can only be used for accessing Open Banking APIs of the ASPSPs based in the UK, while QWAC and QSealC can also be used for accessing PSD2 APIs of EU-based ASPSPs (in case the TPP's license allows that). Also in general qualified certificates fall under eIDAS regulation and have application outside open banking (especially QSealC). And yes, qualified certificates can only be issued by Qualified Trust Service Providers (aka QTSP). The list of QTSPs can be found here: https://esignature.ec.europa.eu/efda/tl-browser/#/screen/home (not sure if the UK list is still updated).